# Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse ClassNotFoundException for GcsFilename

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am trying to run Google's standard App Engine locally within Eclipse. I need to save a file to Cloud Storage. One of the classes I am using is GcsFilename. I am getting a "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsFilename" exception when I run my application.

I had to add the jar appengine-gcs-client-08.jar to my build path to get the code to compile. When it runs I get the exception mentioned above. Currently the project also includes the following libraries: BigQuery API, BigQuery Data Transfer API, and Cloud Storage. It also has these external jars: axis-1.4.jar, commons-discovery-05.jar, jasxrpc-api-1.1.jar, and wsdl5j-1.6.3.jar

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was wrong in my original answer here: the `com.google.appengine.tools` is ok and indeed [there is a tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/building-app/cloud-storage) using the approach you describe.  That tutorial describes the dependencies required when using Maven or Gradle.

You can also use [Cloud Tools for Eclipse](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/)'s [Libraries management feature](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/libraries) to install the Cloud Storage client libraries into your app, but that uses a different set of classes.